The disk usage of MINIO cluster exceeds expectations
I deployed a MINIO cluster using 10 machines through Docker, with each machine utilizing a 150GB drive. Theoretically, I should be able to store more than 500GB of content on this MINIO cluster, but in reality, the actual storage capacity falls far short of this expectation.
Minio Version: RELEASE.2023-03-24T21-41-23Z
The service startup command is: server http://node1/data -address "9000"
The Minio console shows that 100GB of content has been stored, with 14.9M objects.The actual usage scenario is as follows:



Node
Driver Num
Total Memory
Used Memory




Node1
1
150G
97G


Node2
1
150G
97G


Node3
1
150G
97G


......
......
......
......


Node10
1
150G
97G



I don't know why the actual capacity utilized by each machine is almost approaching the actual file size stored. Are there any parameters that I can optimize in my MinIO cluster?

I've had a similar question, where the Minio cluster stats report a much higher amount of free capacity, while the actual drives are approaching their max usage. I don't understand how Minio determines that it could, say, provide another 250G of space, while each of 3 drives only has 60G of free space remaining.
